# Is there a way to "narrow" ("impoverish") an interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In a project that includes several front-end apps and several tens of microservices we have a private npm repository that contains some "commons" for those front-end apps. Naturally, commons include some models in TS, like

```
interface IUser {
    id: string;
    login: string;
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

This is fine for the apps to be "on the same page"; however, in rapid development all microservices don't necessarily return the same model in their API responses. Like some microservice may return an object that's "enriched" compared to the interface in commons:

```
interface IUser {
    id: string;
    login: string;
    name: string;
    ...
    extraField1: someType1;
    extraField2: someType2;
}
```

Enriched types can be easily defined via another interface which extends the one from commons:

```
interface IUserEnriched extends IUser {
    extraField1: someType1;
    extraField2: someType2;
}
```

and that is used from time to time outside commons. But there also are cases where a microservice returns an "impoverished" object:

```
interface IUserImpoverished {
    id: string;
    /* no login: string; here; or may be it's optional, unlike in the common interface */
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

**I wonder if TypeScript has some way to "deduce" such an interface from `IUser` instead of duplicating code (?).** This case is actually more problematic in terms of updating commons: if we change `IUser` in commons by adding some fields, it is unlikely that any app won't get built (at least when we *read* data from API), it's just we don't use those new properties; on the contrary, if one changes `IUser` in commons by *removing* the `login` property, they also will need to create "enriched" interfaces in each app that actually uses `login`. So it's really desirable to be able to "impoverish" interfaces too.

I've tried to google using keyword "narrow [TS interface]" but narrowing is a term used to describe a different case. May be you know the correct term – if so, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Omit<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) utility type to "impoverish" object types `T` by removing properties with keys of type `K` this way.  You can make a type alias:

```
type TUserImpoverished = Omit<IUser, "login">;
```

or, if you need an interface:

```
interface IUserImpoverished extends Omit<IUser, "login"> { }
```

Note that the second parameter to omit is the [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) `"login"`. You can see that the omitted key is removed from the known keys of the resulting object type:

```
const impoverishedUser: IUserImpoverished = { id: "1", name: "Alice" };
```

Note that if you want to remove more than one key you can do it by specifying that `K` is a union of the relevant key types:

```
type TUserFurtherImpoverished = Omit<IUser, "login" | "name">;
const furtherImpoverishedUser: TUserFurtherImpoverished = { id: "2" };
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXBAjFAvFA3lAQwC4oAGKAXwFgAoUSWRFNAJmzygCMTNqapaASwB2wCACcAZgQDG0AJIBVGBLy0oGwQBMSMYOJEBzANzqNAGziGRu-UdP8NwgklsHhJ2nyGiJ0uVBKKuIAosIGMgAWEFpQEAAeYsJaMIHKqrhmcYniBABighDmWui6TKiQ6A4a2fr5hcUsZUgVECwO3nRoUMjp4vIIYHAAbhKCMNGxOADyCILAADxBEgA0UABEltbC6wB8DiJiUrIKfQNDowYTMbUQyamz80t9a5tWInscfDJwwnpQgkGIzG1y0fRIy36QMu40m7Hw2hI63Q6zWzlcGwAguZBHJ1pQHLR6NBesE8gBXcTAaJQi4guEzOaLSGvLYfKAAHw26IgewcPz+wCgkkp1Ik52BV0m4J6fQpVJpEphoPhAJ0GxY+IoxiAA)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your use case but you can juggle utility types like so:

```js
interface IUser {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

type IUserImpoverished = Pick<IUser, 'id'>;

const impoverishedUser: IUserImpoverished = {
  id: 'meh'
};
```